# Certs-Engine and Magento Certified Developer Exam

Tags: certification

I'm trying to take the exam for the Magento Certified Developer.

I wonder if the answers provided to each question are realiable?

Because when I came to this question today,

[image: question]

I am confused can some one tell weather it is C,D or E

Comment: Why you try M1 exam. This is outdated and you can't take this exam through Magento and Kryterion.

Comment: Additionally those sites oftentimes have actual questions from the exam instead of similar questions. It’s better to pass on your own merit than by memorizing answers. Otherwise it’s only a certification on paper

Answer (score 4):

Answers  C,D **and** E are correct:

Usually for an EAV model

the resource model extends `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity`

the collection extends `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection`

the setup class extends `\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup`

while a model extends `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` or `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel` and a helper extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`

Comment: Good explanation. +1